# AngularJS - State name passed into controller doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and I can't figure out why this isn't working.

When I call `{{$state.current.name}}` in my view it works perfectly fine, but as soon as I try to pass it to my controller, the state gets "lost".

Here is my setup:

Module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

        .run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
            $rootScope.$state = $state;
            $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        })
        //followed by boilerplate ui router setup
```

View:

`<home-nav-bar></home-nav-bar>`

Directive:

```
angular.module('app')
            .directive('homeNavBar', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    templateUrl: 'homeNavBarView.html',
                    controller: 'navCtrl'
                };
            })
})();
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app')
            .controller('navCtrl', function ($state, $scope) {
                   alert($state.current.name); //returns empty
            });
})();
```

At this point I am clueless as to why I can get the state name in the view but not in my controller..

Comment: If you inject the `$rootScope` to your controller instead and do `alert($rootScope.$state.current.name` what do you get ?

Comment: I believe you can do $scope.$root.$state or... $scope.root.$state

Comment: @OmriAharon, it shows on the first refresh, but it becomes null on the second click

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/plunker?

Answer (score 4):

Well, `ui-router` [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) say you can access current state's config object using the `current` property of `$state`, so there is absolutely no need to attach anything to `$rootScope`. I have just tested something along the lines of (simplified a bit for readability):

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('SomeCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {  
  console.log($state.current);
});
```

The result in Chrome console is:

```
Object {url: "/some", templateUrl: "app/some.html", controller: "SomeCtrl", name: "some"}
```

So as you can see all information should be available along with the name.

Comment: The controller should be recreated each time you transition into a state. Note though that parent controllers will not be reloaded automatically, so if you go from `parent.a` to `parent.b` then a new controller will be created for `b` but not for `parent`.

Comment: For some reason, the state change does not get tracked. On the first load the state name is correct, but as soon as I change states, the state object becomes empty

Comment: In any case if you're still having problems with this a plnkr or fiddle or whatnot would really go a long way...